# DAX measure to return alternative result for total

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to create DAX measure returning different value for total in table visual?  I would like it for conditional formatting for whatever dimension split in table visuals. But since conditional formatting does not work for totals I do not want to display it for that line.

I need something like:

```
IF(condition_identifying_total_line, "Alternative result", [TrafficLightIcon])
```

**Edit.** This does exactly what I want but I hope for more elegant approach or any other suggestions:

```
IsTotal =
COUNTROWS(FactTable) =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( FactTable ),
    ALLSELECTED ( FactTable)
)
```

This measure works for whatever dimension split of Sales figures in table visual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up using [INSCOPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/isinscope-function-dax) function:

```
IsTotal = NOT(
   ISINSCOPE(products[dimension1])
|| ISINSCOPE(products[dimension2])
|| ISINSCOPE(stores[dimension1])
|| ISINSCOPE(stores[dimension2])
)
```

Unfortunately it requires hard coding all dimensions by which we want to slice or group visuals.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of options depending on exactly what you want to do. I suggest taking a look a the following functions for ideas:

- [ISFILTERED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/isfiltered-function-dax)
- [ISCROSSFILTERED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/iscrossfiltered-function-dax)
- [HASONEFILTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/hasonefilter-function-dax)
- [HASONEVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/hasonevalue-function-dax)
- [FILTERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/filters-function-dax)
- [SELECTEDVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function)

---

For example, if `Sales` broken out by a column `A`, here are a couple possible approaches:

```
Sales = IF( HASONEVALUE( T[A] ), SUM ( T[Sales] ), <Alternative Result> )

Sales = IF( ISFILTERED ( T[A] ), <Alternative Result>, SUM ( T[Sales] ) )
```

Comment: My question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202628/traffic-lights-in-power-bi-which-work-also-for-totals The measure `TrafficLight = UNICHAR(11044)` after conditional formatting show nasty black spot in total line, which is not affected by conditional formatting. I do not want it to show up. I want to detect totals, regardless if it is filtered or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can find full documentation for how to handle granularities from the SQLBI website here: https://www.daxpatterns.com/handling-different-granularities/

Hope this helps!
William