# Report Builder - Unicode Symbols - toggle the Print Layout button

Tags: reporting-services, unicode, dax, reportbuilder3.0

Reference to community.powerbi.com  Service forum here for SO help

Basically was having issues with glyph (unicode symbols) display on Power BI Paginated Reports, PBI Service, PBI Desktop and Dashboards.

Solution found for Paginated Reports in that only Segoe UI Symbol font works for the complete set of unicode fonts I am using.

Current thinking is that for dashboards the custom visual like deneb with html usage will work.  So far I have only had time to test this direction with HTML Content custom visual with html and works for what I need.

[Report Builder - Unicode Symbols - toggle the Print Layout button](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Report-Builder-Unicode-Symbols-toggle-the-Print-Layout-button/td-p/2643629)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202628/traffic-lights-in-power-bi-which-work-also-for-totals/57421656#57421656

Comment: https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U25A0.pdf   Geometric Shapes are part of Unicode 14.0

Comment: updates made 14-12-2022 to pbi community thread link shown above

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: @NicoHaase  Thank you, I was just trying to source help from so to my question on pbi, links above.  Issue now solved.  The fun I am now having is with dashboards where  custom font size functionality is not available with the matrix/table visual like colour under conditional formatting option for each column.

Answer (score 0):

[Power BI Paginated Report Builder - Unicode Symbols - toggle the Print Layout button](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Power-BI-Paginated-Report-Builder-Unicode-Symbols-toggle-the/m-p/2975568#M183233)

Basically Segoe UI Symbol font saved the situation in pbi paginated report builder.  Using Segoe UI Symbol font ensures that all glyph symbols are displayed.
But with pbi desktop you are out of luck with custom font size functionality is not available.

Please vote from here within the pbi community is to help garner public support for functionality changes to the pbi products from the m$ developer teams.
[Power BI Desktop - conditional font formatting like font size, font size offset, font family etc](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-Desktop-conditional-font-formatting-like-font-size-font/td-p/2999674)

Comment: Why do you need any vote? Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I thought it was obvious from my comment against the original question 'custom font size functionality is not available ...'   I would have thought the links to my posts in the pbi community for all the gory detail would be enough also.   I did say above that Segoe UI Symbol font was needed in pbi paginated report builder but pbi desktop a different path will be needed.

Comment: The need for votes within the pbi community is to help garner public support for functionality changes to the pbi products from the m$ developer teams.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it